# I'm building a dynamic form in Android using RecyclerView and I need to save the state of the form

Tags: android, forms, dynamic, android-recyclerview

First of all I'm not native english speaker so I'm sorry if there is any grammar or spilling mistakes but I'm really trying to do my best here.

OK, I'm developing an application in android system for e-commerce, the user can add any product to sell, but as you know there are many filters questions.

For example if the user want to sell a car he has to select the model and the company of the car, but if he want to sell a mobile then the questions changed to select the storage for example and the model and the company questions will be deleted,  so the questions here are dynamic.

I already developed the form using RecyclerView and its look great.

[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x23o5.png)

[figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrkCt.png)

[figure3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYEwo.png)

The problem that when I used

```
notifydatasetchanged
```

The form data get mixed!

I solved this problem using

```
notifyItemRangeRemoved and notifyItemRangeInserted
```

So it's working great, but I still confused why this is happened?

The second problem that is the dynamic form is a fragment called "DynamicFormBuilderFragment" and sometimes I have to replace it with another fragment like "Google Maps fragment" for example the problem that when I call back the "DynamicFormBuilderFragment" all my data is Lost and the form get duplicated!

Like this

[figure4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/465jt.png)

I want to put some codes but really I don't know what to put because they all are too long and complex, but for start I think this problem because I made the RecyclerView.Adapter not static, I will try for now to made it static and see what happens, but I still need your help please.

Thanks for reading and I wish to you a great day and happy coding.

**Update**

this is my java files and classes

```
AddAds.class extends ActionBarActivity
DynamicFormBuilderFragment.class extends Fragment // is contain RecyclerView + Adapter + LoadToAdapter + questions classes and it's where dynamic form get build.
GoogleMaps.class extends Fragment
```

Comment: The links to your pictures do not work without logging in to google drive. Please provide public links.

Comment: Further i do not understand that you use RecyclerView to build a form (what ever that would be). You could use it for a ListView though.

Comment: OK, I re-uploaded the images to Imgur, and I used RecyclerView because I think its more fast than the regular listview.

Comment: It is very difficult to see what is what. Moreover i do not understand what you mean with 'dynamic form' in `the dynamic form is inside a fragment`.

Comment: We know already that you use a RecyclerView in it. But are there more views in it? And how are the items of the RecyclerView build up? (what is what?).

Comment: OK I added new details, I hope now it's clear

Comment: No. I wish to you a great day and happy coding. ;-). Bye.

Comment: Lol, Thank you for trying to help me at least. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SLOVED!

I Replaced the RecyclerView with the ListView and it's working great now so thanks @greenapps.

I think it's a bug so I will reported to Google.

Comment: Is the problem with recycler view still standing?